# Modifying JSON Data Returned from C# AJAX Call

Tags: c#, json, ajax

I'm doing an ajax call to retrieve JSON data returned from a query. My JSON is returning the following (accurately):

```
[{
    "label": "",
    "value": "2302"
}, {
    "label": "9 - Contract set-up in EPICOR",
    "value": "2280"
}, {
    "label": "2 - Verify PO received",
    "value": "2279"
}, {
    "label": "7 - Review quote and prepare team for meeting",
    "value": "2281"
}]
```

But I need it to actually return:

```
{
    "options": {
        "logan_dvprTasks.taskID": {
            [{
                "label": "",
                "value": "2302"
            }, {
                "label": "9 - Contract set-up in EPICOR",
                "value":"2280"
            }, {
                "label": "2 - Verify PO received",
                "value":"2279"
            }, {
                "label": "7 - Review quote and prepare team for meeting",
                "value":"2281"
            }]
        }
    }
```

The code I have that generates the JSON is:

```
public IEnumerable<updatetasks> GetAllItems(string dvprid)
{
    string stringSQL = "sqlStatement goes here";

    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["loganWebConn"]
                                            .ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = stringSQL;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var updatetasks = new updatetasks();
                    updatetasks.label = reader["taskName"].ToString();
                    updatetasks.value = reader["taskID"].ToString();
                    yield return updatetasks;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I modify my C# code to add in these two items at the start of the JSON object?

Comment: I've better formatted your code, especially the JSON to help illustrate the structure you need to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By returning the object you want instead.

Change your ajax call to this method and return it as such.

```
public object MyCall(string dvprid)
{
    return new
    {
        options = new
        {
            logan_dvprTasks = GetAllItems(dvprid)
        };
    };
}
```

Keep in mind that `.` (dot) is not valid on a C# identifier, therefore I called your `logan_dvprTasks.taskID` simply `logan_dvprTasks`.

If you mean `taskID` to be a property of `logan_dvprTasks`, the resulting JSON would be

```
{"options":{"logan_dvprTasks":{"taskID":[...]}}}
```

Comment: I think your addendum about the `taskID` property is correct, because I'm fairly certain that an object without a property name that is only an array is not valid JSON. What you have on your last night is formatted correctly.

Comment: Yea, I believe his example code has one extra `{` at `{"options":{"logan_dvprTasks.taskID":{[...]}}`, since it closes with two `}` instead of three. I answered as if it was `{"options":{"logan_dvprTasks.taskID":[...]}}`, but corrected the `.taskID` part which is not valid C#